# Workout on restful services for single page applications

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I am just a beginner in Angularjs. I have been trying for consuming WebApi service  by angularjs. I am following [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx3bv.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx3bv.png): http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service   documentation. It has been clearly documented about use of factories and services. I want to perform crud operations  and I am following the same way but I am not even getting the methods called in the Api controller and how can I get the data to be listed in the view?

I have done this: My factory is defined in index.cshtml

In the Main view ie. Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<style>
    .container {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<h2>Practising Angular</h2>
<a href="#/">List</a>
<a href="#/Edit">Edit</a>

<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

    demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { controller: 'SimpleController', templateUrl: 'Home/List' })
                      .when('/Edit', { controller: 'SimpleController', templateUrl: 'Home/Edit' })
                      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });



    demoApp.factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var urlBase = '/api/Customer';
        var dataFactory = {};
        dataFactory.getCustomers = function () {
            return $http.get(urlBase);
        };
        dataFactory.getCustomer = function (id) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + id);
        };
        return dataFactory;
    }]);



    demoApp.controller('customersController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', function ($scope, dataFactory) {

        $scope.status;
        $scope.customers;
        getCustomers();

        function getCustomers() {
            dataFactory.getCustomers()
                .success(function (custs) {
                    $scope.customers = custs;
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
                });
        }



    }]);

</script>
```

I have this controller which runs by default as it is an MVC 4.0 project and "Home Controller" and "Index" is defined in the route.

```
namespace Routing_Angular.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult List()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
}
```

The List and Edit Action methods are returned as partialviews because they will act as views to render data in angular js.

So, this is what I have in both of the partial views..

List.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<h2>Listing the users in order </h2>

<div class="container">
    Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="objCust in customers  | filter:filter.name">{{objCust.name }}-{{objCust.city}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    Customer Name:<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" /><br />
    Customer city:<br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" /><br />
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add customer</button>
</div>




Edit.cshtml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit  the particular user. Things are under construction</h2>


<h2>Listing the users in order </h2>

<div class="container">
    Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" ng-model="city" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="objCust in customers | filter:city">{{objCust.name }}-{{objCust.city}}
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

This is the Api controller/Service that is being getting called from Factory in the index.cshtml. But none of the methods are getting called. How the data got from the factory objects will be shown in the View?

ApiController

```
namespace Routing_Angular.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : ApiController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customer/
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            CustomerService ObjService = new CustomerService();
            var Clients = ObjService.GetClients();
            if (Clients.Count < 1) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<tblreferralService>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, Clients);
        }

        // GET api/customers/5
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            CustomerService ObjService = new CustomerService();
            var Client = ObjService.GetClient(id);
            if (Client == null) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            return Request.CreateResponse<tblreferralService>(HttpStatusCode.OK, Client);
        }

    }
}
```

Below I am attaching the image for project structure. It is just a basic structure.

[image]

Comment: I would not use partial views, just only use web api for data, and build that partials using ng-include or as controls using directives.

About the way to retrieve data, where does it fail? Did you hit the line of code in javascript that makes the $http request, what do you get back success or error? I would as well use F12 developer tools on the navigator and check what does return the request.

Another point to test, can you reach that web api method just using the navigator or a tool like postman. I think with that additional info we can move forward and find where's the issue.

Comment: Actually I do not know how to call the factory that will ultimately call to the api controller. Unfortunately I am getting no error in console and also there is no call going to server or something.

Comment: I have figured out the problem. The controller used in the routing is different from what defined in module . Now I have started getting internalserver 500 error and my API controller method is not getting hit.

Comment: This are good news, so the issue you are facing now it's more related to server side web api? If you try to reach that web api using directly url/browser or postman (go to google chrome store and download it, it's free and helps a lot on trouble shooting rest based services), can you reach the service?

Comment: No I am not able to hit the service. It throws exception "ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize".